# Use the contents of a div as more Beautful Soup input

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This must be an easy answer since it's the purpose of BS4, but I'm stumped.

I have an HTML page that consists of some number of main divs, each containing similar HTML.  I want to loop through the main divs and then parse each one's contents.  I have the parser all good to go without the loop (that is, if it's a page with only one main div, I'm good).  I'd rather not delve too deeply into changing all that code if possible.

So it looks something like this:

```
<div class = main1>
    <div class = price>$50</div>
    <div class = title>Blah</div>
</div>
<div class = main2>
    <div class = price>$150</div>
    <div class = title>Blah blah</div>
</div>
<div class = main3>
    <div class = price>$500</div>
    <div class = title>Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

My code snippet:

```
multi_products = self.souped_text.find_all("div", class=re.compile("main"))
            if len(multi_products) > 1:
                products = []
                for product_page in multi_products:
                    self.souped_text = BeautifulSoup(product_page.contents[0])
                    products.append(self.parse())
```

Which I think should work, but then nothing after seems to parse--my thought is that product_page.contents[0] is not as Soupy as I'd like, as I'm consistently getting a "NoneType' object has no attribute 'string' or whatever, as if Soup functions aren't working on the input. Tested types, type(product_page) = < class 'bs4.element.Tag'> and type(self.souped_text) = < class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>

Using OSX, Python 2.7, BS4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was double-souping.  Should have been `self.souped_text = product_page`